How to Preserve hyperlinks after converting from Excel to PDF using Telerik PdfFormatProvider vb.net
Hello Dear Devs I have an issue while converting xlsx file to pdf; the hyperlinks are not preserved / do not exist on the pdf (ps: they exist in the xlsx file)
here is the conversion function =>
Private Function ExportExcelToPdf(localFile As String, convertToPDF As Boolean) As String
    If convertToPDF Then
        Try
            Dim workbook As New Telerik.Windows.Documents.Spreadsheet.Model.Workbook()

            Dim xlsxProvider As New Telerik.Windows.Documents.Spreadsheet.FormatProviders.OpenXml.Xlsx.XlsxFormatProvider()
            Using input As New FileStream(localFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
                workbook = xlsxProvider.Import(input)
            End Using

            'Dim worksheet As Telerik.Windows.Documents.Spreadsheet.Model.Worksheet = workbook.ActiveWorksheet


            Dim pdfProvider As New Telerik.Windows.Documents.Spreadsheet.FormatProviders.Pdf.PdfFormatProvider()
            Dim pdfFilePath As String = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() & Guid.NewGuid().ToString() & ".pdf"

            Using output As New FileStream(pdfFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
                pdfProvider.Export(Workbook, output)
            End Using


            localFile = pdfFilePath

            Return localFile



        Catch ex As Exception
            Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex).Throw()
        Finally
            ' Release resources if needed
        End Try
    Else
        Return localFile
    End If
End Function

any idea why or any open source alternative (the company has only the telerik license)
i tried NPOI to read xlsx file and convert using pdfSarp but it do not conserve the xlsx formating pageSetup ...
I would really appriciate any help
Thank you
Telerik
NOIP/PdfSharp

Anyway I didn't fint a solution so i re created the whole pdf using pdfSharp
